# Trigger no mysql copiando dados na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa Tarde,

Tenho uma tabela que contem os campos id_documento (int) AI , nome_usuario e nosso_numero(int). Queria atraves de uma trigger se for possivel que após eu inserir um novo documento o campo nosso numero recebesse o campo id_documento formatado tipo LPAD(id_documento, 8, '0'). Gostaria de uma ajuda para desenvolver essa trigger visto q são inseridos varios documentos de cada vez em uma unica ação. Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Ja tentei

```
If nosso_numero is null then 
UPDATE tb_documentos_emitidos SET nosso_numero = LPAD(id_documento, 8, '0') 
WHERE tb_documentos.nosso_numero = null ; 
end if
```

Agora tentei

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `amoruna`.`tgr_nossonumero`
BEFORE INSERT ON `amoruna`.`tb_documentos_emitidos`
FOR EACH ROW
If (NEW.nosso_numero IS NULL) THEN
        SET NEW.nosso_numero = (LPAD(NEW.id_documentos, 8, '0'));
end if
```

Funciona se eu informar o valor de forma manual do campo id_documentos.

Mas o campo é autoincrementado e se for colocado o regisro automaticamente não funciona.

Comment: coloca o que você já tentou

Comment: coloca na pergunta velho. qualquer informação que pode ajudar a responder sua pergunta tem que está lá

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO E COMPARTILHANDO

BASTA SUBSTITUIR O CAMPO `ID DOCUMENTO` POR

```
select auto_increment from information_schema.tables 
where table_name = 'tb_documentos_emitidos' and table_schema = 'amoruna'
```

AI A INSTRUÇÃO FICA ASSIM

```
If (NEW.nosso_numero IS NULL) THEN
        SET NEW.nosso_numero = (LPAD((select auto_increment from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'tb_documento_emitidos' and table_schema = 'amoruna'), 8, '0'));
```

essa instrução retorna sempre o próximo número de auto incremento. Espero ter ajudado.